# How to run a code-generator on the top of another code-generator?

Tags: flutter, dart

Using the [source_gen](https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen) stack to make a code generator, how can I make a generator that generates code that would be the input of another generator (more specifically `json_serializable`)?

For example, consider:

```dart
class Example extends Generator {
  @override
  String generate(LibraryReader library, BuildStep buildStep) {
    return '''
@JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
class Person {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final DateTime dateOfBirth;
  Person({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});
  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _PersonFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _PersonToJson(this);
}
''';
  }
}
```

This is an example of a code-generator that output code which then needs to be sent to `json_serializable`

What can I do so that `json_serializable` correctly generates here?

Comment: I don't have an answer but [this link](https://pub.dev/packages/build_config) might point you in a good direction? I'm also interested. I had bookmarked that link to do further research

Comment: I am halfway through to understand the case for your question. can you elaborate more? there is two way to solve this either by calling the actual method which outputs the part file of that JSON or by using a manual step to configure and invoke part builder our self. 

There is third way to run the command using dart ```await Process.start('bash',arguments,runInShell: true);``` but it's kind of a last resort to play.

actually I just tried all code generation logics one day ago on this repo [link](https://github.com/parthdave93/FlutterRouteGen) so.. I think I can be helpful.

Comment: It's about composing code generator, such that I can write one that depends on another one. This way I won't have to fork its sources for maintainability purpose.

Comment: The generation step must work in a single `flutter generate`/`pub run build_runner build`. Otherwise it'd be very unusual to use.

Answer (score 7):

Check the build.yaml config file documentation for more info, but I think you should use the [`applies_builders` param](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/build_config/README.md#defining-builders-to-apply-to-dependents) that allows to execute another build after the defined one.

The example shows a builder that generates .tar.gz files and then executes another build that takes the .tar.gz files as input

```
builders:
  # The regular builder config, creates .tar.gz files.
  regular_builder:
    import: "package:my_package/builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["myBuilder"]
    build_extensions: {".dart": [".tar.gz"]}
    auto_apply: dependents
    apply_builders: [":archive_extract_builder"]
post_process_builders:
  # The post process builder config, extracts .tar.gz files.
  extract_archive_builder:
    import: "package:my_package/extract_archive_builder.dart"
    builder_factory: "myExtractArchiveBuilder"
    input_extensions: [".tar.gz"]
```

so with `source_gen` you should implement for your build

```
applies_builders: ["source_gen|combining_builder", "json_serializable"]
```

and configure the other builder

```
json_serializable:
    import: "package:json_serializable/builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["jsonSerializable"]
    build_extensions: {".dart": ["json_serializable.g.part"]}
    auto_apply: dependents
    build_to: cache
    applies_builders: ["source_gen|combining_builder"]
```

Comment: What I should pass in the [apply_builders] property?

Comment: can you show a complete example of a `build.yaml` file that runs that configures `json_serializable` to run after a builder?

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: It didn't work because I was using `SharedPartBuilder` and no `SharedPartBuilder` is able to resolve the Dart code emitted by another `SharedPartBuilder`. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976480/how-to-run-json-serializable-over-output-of-another-builder

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible just with annotation because there maybe two packages that both have the `@JsonSerializable` annotation

There are two situtations :

- You know what other generators should run after your generator.

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59605830/6877472 is one of the solutions
  - you can use the other generator's code in your own generator and call their generator's.generate function. example code:

```dart
class Example extends Generator {
    @override
    String generate(LibraryReader library, BuildStep buildStep) {
      return JsonSerializable().generate('''
          @JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
          class Person {
            final String firstName;
            final String lastName;
            final DateTime dateOfBirth;
            Person({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});
            factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _PersonFromJson(json);
            Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _PersonToJson(this);
          }
        ''');
     }

}
```

- You don't know what other generators should run after your generator.

Unfortunately currently there is no way to tell the source_gen that your generator may produce a code that needs code generation.

I created an issue here https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/issues/442 if you want to subscribe

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your example code, but 1) `JsonSerializable` class is not a generator and 2) `JsonSerializableGenerator.generate()` doesn't take `String` as an input, but `(LibraryReader library, BuildStep buildStep)`

Answer (score -3):

You can decode the JSON by calling the `jsonDecode()` function, with the JSON string as the method argument.

```
Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(jsonString);

print('Howdy, ${user['name']}!');
print('We sent the verification link to ${user['email']}.');
```

Now, Use the `User.fromJson()` constructor, for constructing a new User instance from a map structure and a `toJson()` method, which converts a User instance into a map.

**employee.dart**

```
class Employee {
  final String name;
  final String id;

  Employee(this.name, this.id);

  Employee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        id = json['id'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
    {
      'name': name,
      'id': id,
    };
}
```

`json_serializable` is an automated source code generator that generates the JSON serialization boilerplate for you.

You need one regular dependency, and two dev dependencies to include `json_serializable` in your project.

```
dependencies:
  json_annotation: ^0.2.3

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^0.8.0
  json_serializable: ^0.5.0
```

For more details on JSON serialization you can refer [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)

you can also use the [Smoke](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/smoke) library.

It's a subset of the Mirrors functionality but has both a Mirrors-based and a Codegen-based implementation. It's written by the PolymerDart team, so it's as close to "Official" as we're going to get.

While developing, it'll use the Mirrors-based encoding/decoding; but for publishing you can create a small transformer that will generate code.

Seth Ladd created [a code sample here](https://gist.github.com/sethladd/34b0d812b29c3bfd9529), which I [extended slightly](https://gist.github.com/DanTup/d0b486d276f49da93e74) to support child-objects:

Comment: No actually he is creating his own build_runner plugin and from which he needs to run another runner kind of like stacking of build runner.

Comment: This is off-topic. `json_serializable` is just an example and could be anything

Comment: i was just giving an example on how smoke library can be used