# How to run json_serializable over output of another builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner

I have made a `SharedPartBuilder` that generates new class annotated with `@JsonSerializable()`. How can I configure `json_serializable` to run over `.part` file generated by my builder before all `.part` files are combined into one `.g.dart`?

Inside `build.yaml`, I have tried adding to my builder
`runs_before: ["json_serializable"]` and
`applies_builders: ["json_serializable"]` or
`applies_builders: ["source_gen|combining_builder", "json_serializable"]` all without success.

EDIT: It seems this is **not possible** when using `SharedPartBuilder`.

> No `SharedPartBuilder` will be able to resolve the Dart code emitted by
> another `SharedPartBuilder`. In order for emitted code to be used with
> the `Resolver` by later build steps, it must write to a `.dart` file
> directly, and should be a different file extension than `.g.dart`.
>
> https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/builder_author_faq.md

Answer (score 1):

This is **not possible** when using `SharedPartBuilder`.

> No `SharedPartBuilder` will be able to resolve the Dart code emitted by
> another `SharedPartBuilder`. In order for emitted code to be used with
> the `Resolver` by later build steps, it must write to a `.dart` file
> directly, and should be a different file extension than `.g.dart`.
>
> https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/builder_author_faq.md

To make it work, I changed my `SharedPartBuilder` to `PartBuilder` and set `generatedExtension` to end with `.dart`.

In `build.yaml` I changed from `build_to: cache` to `build_to: source`.

I can comment out `applies_builders ...` and keep just `runs_before: ["json_serializable"]` and it still works.