# How to run code generator like @riverpod, @json_serializable etc, on generated code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-build, build-runner, riverpod-generator, dart-build

I have many Models such as Customer, Vendor, Employee for which Riverpod provider and notifier gets generated via @riverpod code generator.

My problem is that i have to write repetative code in providers of all model Types.

I just copy file and replace "Customer" with "Employee" or any other model, on which i just need to run build_runner for @riverpod to generate notifiers and providers.

My question is if there is a way to chain this process, such that i would annotate a class with @myCustomGen which would generate code for all model types and all of it would go inside @riverpod generator to give final generated code.

For a note this question is similer to -
[How to run a code-generator on the top of another code-generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503994/how-to-run-a-code-generator-on-the-top-of-another-code-generator)

But i am unable to follow the solution given there. If someone can provide a complete example that would work for me.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.